# Phising warnings (in gmail) when using a gmail address as the website email address. How to avoid it?

Tags: 7, emails

I would like to use a gmail address (a simple email address. i'm not using google apps) as my website's email.

The problem is that users receiving messages from the websites (notifications etc..) have a yellow bar warning them that this might be a fishing attempt.

I thought there might be some settings or best practices to avoid this problem.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this module for a long time without problems. You need to authenticate once, and then all your site emails are sent through the google smtp server.

http://drupal.org/project/smtp

Comment: Thanks for the bump in the right direction. This module seems to do the job!

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the [Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record to avoid getting your emails to go to Spam Folder.

> Sender Policy Framework (SPF) is an email validation system designed
>   to prevent email spam by detecting email spoofing, a common
>   vulnerability, by verifying sender IP addresses. SPF allows
>   administrators to specify which hosts are allowed to send mail from a
>   given domain by creating a specific SPF record (or TXT record) in the
>   Domain Name System (DNS).

There is some [Tools](http://www.openspf.org/Tools) to test your SPF Records

Comment: I didn't know about this email validation system. The module @Neograph734 pointed at is the right one for my problem but your answer is relevant as well. Thank you